# Use objects as field choices in Django model

Tags: python, django, tuples

I'm trying to figure out how to use Django `Field.choices` as strategy selector.

Here's a super simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class AbstractStrategy:
    description = str()

    def do_something(self):
        raise NotImplemented

    def __init__(self, description):
        self.symbol = description

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.description)


class ABCStrategy(AbstractStrategy):
    def do_something(self):
        print('doing something abc way')
        return 


class XYZStrategy(AbstractStrategy):
    def do_something(self):
        print('doing something xyz way')
        return

ABC = ABCStrategy('ABC')
XYZ = XYZStrategy('XYZ')

STRATEGIES = (
(ABC, 'ABC'),
(XYZ, 'XYZ'),
)
```

And then `STRATEGIES` is used as `choices=STRATEGIES`. Later in implementation I theoretically should be able to call strategy from `Model`'s object directly with `strategy_field.do_something` but unfortunately this method doesn't work for now. Is the problem in implementation or it's generally impossible to use choices this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the choice gets saved to the database. The object is too complicated to serialized to string.

A solution is to add this to your model:

```
STRATEGY_CHOICES = (
    ('ABC', 'ABC'),
    ...
)
strategy_mapping = {
    'ABC': ABCStrategy
}

strategy_id = models.CharField(
     choices=STRATEGY_CHOICES
)

@property
def strategy(self):
    return self.strategy_mapping[self.strategy_id]
```

Then you can do `instance.strategy_id = 'ABC'` resulting in `instance.strategy` being `ABCStrategy`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for help!